# Quickly using an array's nearest element to determine if new element is unique

Tags: php, mysql

In PHP, I'm grabbing lists of timestamps from multile SQL tables and creating an array that lists the unique timestamps. The timestamps aren't identical across tables, however, and can vary by as much as a second for the same event. So, for example, I would want 1374531523.343 and 1374531524.012 to be considered the same event, but not 1374531520.342.

I've been using this function to grab the time separation to the nearest event:

```
function findNearest($number, $array, $index = false) {
    $min = abs($number - $array[0]);
    $min_i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $ind => $value) {    
        $mint = abs($number - $value);
        if ($mint < $min) {
            $min = $mint;
            $min_i = $ind;  
        }
    }   
    return ($index ? $min_i : $min);
}
```

(The index part is added because sometimes I need the index of the nearest time,  but this could be moved to a separate function)

So basically I run a simple `SELECT ...` query for each table and check each timestamp:

```
while ($g = $q->fetch_object())
    if (findNearest($g->timestamp, $timestamps) > 1) $timestamps[] = $g->timestamp;
}
```

This works like I want it to, but I'm looking at around 100,000 different timestamps, and will be looking at as many as 500,000 in the future. As `$timestamps` gets larger and larger, this gets slower and slower. I know that's unavoidable, but perhaps there's a better approach which can cut way down on the time, either via MySQL or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps could cut your processing times much faster, but *maybe* will cost you a litle extra effort than you expect.

Assuming that :

1. variable $qry contains your query which store the result to variable $q
2. you have three tables as below
3. you do query, which used by $q in your example, sequentially start from table_1, table_2 and lastly table_3

Table table_1 :

```
id | col_timestamp | parent_table | parent_id
---------------------------------------------
 1 | 1374531523.343|         NULL |      NULL
```

Table table_2 :

```
id | col_timestamp | parent_table | parent_id
---------------------------------------------
 1 | 1374531520.444|         NULL |      NULL
 2 | 1374531524.012|      table_1 |         1
 3 | 1374531556.012|         NULL |         1
 4 | 1374531556.512|      table_2 |         3
```

Table table_3 :

```
id | col_timestamp | parent_table | parent_id
---------------------------------------------
 1 | 1374531521.111|      table_2 |         1
 2 | 1374531523.111|      table_1 |         1
```

Explanation : field parent_table is a varchar to indicate current row is refer to table_1, table_2 or table_3. Field parent_id is refering to field id in table that pointed by field parent_table.

Now, everytime user insert into all tables, we need to check whether similar event already exist in database. We could do this by using trigger. This trigger is fired everytime a row is inserted to table_2 :

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `your_database`$$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `before_insert_table_2`$$

CREATE TRIGGER `before_insert_table_2` BEFORE INSERT 
ON `table_2` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_id INTEGER ;
  DECLARE var_table VARCHAR (10) ;
  SELECT id, parent_table INTO var_id, var_table 
  FROM
    ( SELECT id, 'table_1' AS parent_table, col_timestamp 
      FROM table_1 
      WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
      AND col_timestamp BETWEEN NEW.col_timestamp - 1 AND NEW.col_timestamp + 1 
      UNION
      SELECT id, 'table_2' AS parent_table, col_timestamp 
      FROM table_2 
      WHERE parent_id IS NULL 
      AND col_timestamp BETWEEN NEW.col_timestamp - 1 AND NEW.col_timestamp + 1
    ) 
  ORDER BY ABS(col_timestamp - NEW.col_timestamp), parent_table 
  LIMIT 1 ;
  SET NEW.parent_id = var_id ;
  SET NEW.parent_table = var_table ;
END ;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Do similar step to table_1 and table_3.

Next step is to set parent_table and parent_id into already existing data. You could modify your $qry to get table name and its id and update into associated row. This step only need to be run once.

Next step is to modify your query to get events. This is an example :

```
SELECT 'table_1' original_table, id
FROM table_1 
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 'table_2' original_table, id
FROM table_2
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT 'table_3' original_table, id
FROM table_3
WHERE parent_id IS NULL
```

Last step is to modify your program to implement the changes in database.

Hopefully this help.

Comment: I must admit, after I post my answer, word _a litte extra effort_ is undervalued, but these steps are necessary to process big data. :)

Answer (score 0):

would it be possible to create another MySQL table for the timestamp and an id like:

Table: timestamps

```
time_id | timestamp
--------+---------------
1       | 1374531523.343
```

And then use the id to relate to all the other tables that use that same timestamp similar to:

Other Table(s):

```
table_id | timestamps_time_id | etc...
---------+--------------------+-------
1        | 1                  | etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can edit your query instead of processing the results with PHP:

```
SELECT time FROM table GROUP BY time DIV 1
```

Comment: The problem here is that the timestamps are unique within each table, but not across tables.

Comment: Ok, clear. Can't you use `DATE_DIFF`: `SELECT time FROM table1, table2 WHERE DATEDIFF(millisecond p,table1.time,table2.time) < 1000`

Comment: 'millisecond p' should be without ' p'. Can't edit answer on iPad ;-)